# LINQ: ...Where(x => x.Contains(string that start with "foo"))

Tags: c#, linq

Given a collection of the following class:

```
public class Post
{
    ...
    public IList<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Is there an easy way to get all `Post`s that contain a tag starting with "foo" using LINQ?

```
var posts = new List<Post>
{
    new Post { Tags = new[] { "fooTag", "tag" }},
    new Post { Tags = new[] { "barTag", "anyTag" }},
    new Post { Tags = new[] { "someTag", "fooBarTag" }}
};

var postsWithFooTag = posts.Where(x => [some fancy LINQ query here]);
```

`postsWithFooTag` should now contain items 1 and 3 of `posts`.

Comment: Thanks to all! Is there the possibility to do the "StartsWith comparison" case insensitive?

Comment: Use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use string's `StartsWith`

```
var postsWithFooTag = posts.Where(x => x.Tags.Any(y => y.StartsWith("foo")));
```

[`x.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336759.aspx#anySimple) will check if any element matches some condition. [`StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452.aspx) checks if the element starts with a certain string.

The above returned:

```
new Post { Tags = new[] { "fooTag", "tag" }},
new Post { Tags = new[] { "someTag", "fooBarTag" }}
```

To make it case `insensitive` use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

```
var postsWithFooTag = posts.Where(x => x.Tags.Any(y => y.StartsWith("FoO", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

Returns:

```
new Post { Tags = new[] { "fooTag", "tag" }},
new Post { Tags = new[] { "someTag", "fooBarTag" }}
```

while `StartsWith("FoO")` returns no results.

Comment: +1 and accepted answer for the additional info and the case insensitive example. Thanks!

Comment: ...and i thought i was so clever when i created a `StartsWithComparer`

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
var postsWithFooTag = posts.Where(x => x.Tags.Any(y => y.StartsWith("foo")))
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will work for what you're trying to do.

`posts.Where(p => p.Tags.Any(t => t.StartsWith("foo")))`

Answer (score 2):

```
var tag = "foo";
var postsWithFooTag = 
  posts.Where( p=> p.Tags.Any( t => t.StartsWith(tag)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `x => x.Tags.Any(tag => tag.StartsWith("foo"))`