# LINQ for getting all entries of a IEnumerable<string> which start with the same characters

Tags: c#, linq

I got an `IEnumerable<string>` and I want to gather all entries which start with the same characters.
For example:

```
Hans
Hannes
Gustav
Klaus
Herbert
Hanne
```

Now I want to find all entries where the first `2` characters are the same which would return `Hans, Hannes, Hanne`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ: ...Where(x => x.Contains(string that start with "foo"))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916093/linq-wherex-x-containsstring-that-start-with-foo)

Comment: if those 2 characters are known then @Steve comment is the way to go otherwise you should consider a `GroupBy`/`ToLookup` where the key is that substring of 2

Comment: Sorry if my question is too unclear, I don't think it's a duplicate of the linked question because the characters aren't known. I only know for how much characters (in this case two) I want to search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `.GroupBy`

```
list.GroupBy(x=>x.Substring(0, n)).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count()).First()
```

Where `n` is the number of char you want to compare.

Can also add a `Where` to filter any requirements you may have:

```
list.GroupBy(x=>x.Substring(n))
   .Where(x=>x.Count() > 1)
   .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count())
   .First()
```

Complete example:

```
     var lst = new string[]
     {
        "Hans",
        "Hannes",
        "Gustav",
        "Klaus",
        "Herbert",
        "Hanne"
     };
     var source = lst.GroupBy(x => x.Substring(0, 2)).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).First()
     Console.WriteLine(source.Key);
     Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", source));
```

Comment: I know the point is to give some sample but that's some bad `Where` example here (don't hit me) ; `OrderByDescending` and then some `FirstOrDefault(x => x.Count () > 1)` would do the same and be clearer

Comment: When I try your solution with my sample data it returns an empty `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>>`. I feel like `Substring` isn't working here since it's parameter is `startIndex`.

Comment: Fixed substring, used first, and added full example

Comment: Thanks alot, @Cine